# 301 Redirects from old site to new site for SEO Value

Tags: seo

We have an old site that has 10 years of SEO value.  We created a new site that is related, but not a direct replacement.  Should I do 301 redirects from the old to new?  Also, are we penalized if we just redirect to the home page and not a 1 to 1 match?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is about SEO

Answer (score -1):

NO problem. Just do a `301 redirect`. Everything will be ok. Your old sites SEO value will be same until you close the website. And if your new site maintain the same SEO optimization you will be rewarded same value as like the old site within few months. Hope you have got what i mean.